# Label printing is blurry - wpf

Tags: wpf, label, blurry, barcode-printing

i´m trying to print a barcode on a **argox os-214** that i create using this framework http://barcoderender.codeplex.com/ but is always blurry, can´t read using a scanner.

I already tried some other solutions, but i still dont get it, and if using the "Bartender" the printer software, work´s just fine. The label size is 40mmX60mm and is set up in windows printing.
follow the prototype code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Code39BarcodeDraw code39 = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code39WithChecksum;
      pcImage.Source = GetImageStream(code39.Draw("1234567", 13));
    }

    public static BitmapSource GetImageStream(System.Drawing.Image myImage)
    {
      var bitmap = new Bitmap(myImage);
      IntPtr bmpPt = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
      BitmapSource bitmapSource =
       System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
             bmpPt,
             IntPtr.Zero,
             Int32Rect.Empty,
             BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

      bitmapSource.Freeze();

      return bitmapSource;
    }

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
      bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

      if (result.HasValue && result.Value) {
        pcImage.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(dlg.PrintableAreaWidth, dlg.PrintableAreaHeight));
        pcImage.Arrange(new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), pcImage.DesiredSize));

        dlg.PrintVisual(pcImage, "Print a Large Image");
      }
    }
  }
```

This is just a image component... Well, any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.
The printer have 203dpi, and it´s wpf.
[Label with the blurry code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SlxB.jpg)

Comment: Try to set these properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805677/why-everything-in-wpf-is-blurry on pcImage before calling measure and arrange

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, i´ve already tried   UseLayoutRounding="True"        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" and unfortunately keep blurry, i will update the question with a label image.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i forgot about this...
But if this could help someone... To print to argox 214-os or other seagull barcode printers you need some default layout like this file (.prn)
for example: barcode.prn

```
n
M0500
O0220
V0
f220
D
L
D11
A2
1a52050007900551063
121100000280089Preco R$ 39,9
121100000490068REGM OGB T-M
Q0001
E
```

where the first seven lines

```
n
M0500
O0220
V0
f220
D
L
D11
A2
```

are always the same-

I'm using this layout

[image: Barcode]

(it´s an old printer, just for test, so i know it seems "blurry"...)
and then the next lines you can see

this if for the barcode 1a5205000790055 + my code(1063)

this for label with the price 121100000280089 + my string with price (Preco R$ 39,9)

and so on...

And I´m printing like this

```
  Printer printer = new Printer(); (RawPrinter library)

  printer.PrintRawFile(dlg.PrintQueue.FullName, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\code39.prn", false);
```

Oh, you could find RawPrint on nuget...Install-Package RawPrint -Version 0.2.0

Or **forget all this and try BARTENDER DESIGNER** just create your label design and export to prn file, but remember to use a printer font, if you use a windows font, will create a prn file with a lot of unwanted characters.