# What Can be Done to Resolve the Font Rendering Issues in WPF applications?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008

It seems like it would behoove me to learn this GDI replacement, WPF.  I dropped some controls on a new WPF project and started looking around.  It's obvious the playing field has changed again.  If the past has taught me anything, I know I need to get this this thing under my belt (like it or not).

That being said, I'm not sure I can get my customers to swallow the fuzzy fonts.  Some of them have trouble reading text on the screen as it is.

I found some mention of this on SO, but no real solutions I can duplicate:

[WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions)

Is it simply that the default font was poorly chosen?  I'd rather not have to hack the registry on customer machines.

I was curious what other developers are doing to overcome this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue, Actually I have the same issue here in my application and I am using WPF 3.5 with VS2010

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Change the font to Tahoma.  Everything should crisp up.  I dislike the default font in Win7 and VS2010.  Changing everything to Tahoma works.  Changing the font in your WPF app via the designer should have the same effect, but I don't really know.  I have been avoiding WPF like the plague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is waiting until [VS2010/.NET 4.0 ships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions/1494126#1494126) (March 2010) a solution for you? If you're only starting to look at WPF now, I wouldn't have thought you'd be shipping a significant app before March. Of course, whether your customers will be willing to upgrade to .NET 4.0 is a different question.

Comment: I cannot find a way to disable the anti-aliasing of text in WPF3.5 and as a result label or button text looks really bad. Ideally I'd like to disable anti aliasing globally for fonts. How can I accomplish this in WPF3.5?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: I don't know, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

There's one answer - upgrade to .net 4.0 and the new, [improved WPF font stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx), which allows for pixel-aligned font rendering.   It took Microsoft actually using WPF for a business app (Visual Studio) for this fix to go in, I notice.

Comment: Is there only way to upgrade to .net4.0 ?, Can't we do it in .net3.5 ?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain as far as I know, there is no way to pixel-align fonts in wpf unless you upgrade to 4+.