# Text rendering still blurry : Best font for WPF application?

Tags: wpf, textrenderer

I know this is a very subjective question but as text rendering in WPF is still an issue I have to make the best out of it.

In WPF Application text tend to become blurry that is no secret. Also there are countless website about this topic and how you get around this problem.
But I wonder ... text blurriness seems to affect some fonts more that others. So I am still looking for the best font available to get around this issue.

So far I am still using Arial and it doesn't look good. But I am sure some other font are more suitable for the task at hand.

Comment: A related thread with lots of information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try with the fonts that have been optimized for ClearType. Typically their names will start with a 'c':

> Many, but not all, fonts that start with C and come installed with Windows Vista (Cambria, Calibri, Corbel, Candara, Consolas, etc...) have been designed to work well with WPF. In addition to these, fonts with robust outlines like Verdana, Georgia, etc… display well on computer screens.

(quoted from [Text Clarity in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/index)).

[image]

[image]

(image source: http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/wpftextclarity.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Verdana it is! A little bit bigger but very beautiful. This font still looks good with the text rotated 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to go with WPF 4, as it has all of the nice changes that they made to get VS2010 looking nice.

Comment: You also have to change the text rendering options, the default setting is the WPF3 setting

Comment: @Paul EDIT: Is this what you're talking about: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/06/07/quick-tip-applying-text-options-throughout-your-wpf-4-application ? `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` and `TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"`