# How to prevent text to pixelize when I use RenderTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, richtextbox, rendertransform

When I use RenderTransform property and scale up a RichTextBox I get magnified text which is pixelized (square text edges).

How I can prevent this?
[image]

EDIT:

I have TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" - when I remove this option everything is fine!

Comment: What do you need `TextFormattingMode` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot claim that i can reproduce this with my current settings:

[image]

That is with a scale of 20. I think this could be dependent on the ClearType system settings, you can try setting [`RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint.aspx) on the RichTextbox, that might enforce it.

Also try setting [`TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textoptions.textrenderingmode.aspx).

**Edit:** [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions) deals with text-rendering quite in-depth and might be helpful.

---

Edit: Check out this weirdness:

```
<TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit"
           FontSize="20" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
     <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
           <ScaleTransform x:Name="trans" ScaleY="10" ScaleX="10"/>
     </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
     <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="20" Duration="0:0:5"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="trans" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
     </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

As soon as a certain scale is reached the text becomes clear for me, really odd...

Comment: If I keep TextOptions.TextFormattingMode = "Display" and add RenderOptions the pixelization stays :(

Comment: `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` seems to effectively kill all efforts to make it look nice...

Comment: What font are you using? Just making sure you aren't using a bitmapped font.

Comment: @Kevin Hsu: I doubt that this is the issue, not even one of my installed fonts pixelates on normal settings.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"

as suggested on:
http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/wpf-text-rendering-quirks-scaletransform