# WPF: Why does text and elements blur if I use dropshadow effect on a parent item

Tags: wpf, xaml, blur, dropshadow

If I add a `DropShadowEffect` to an parent element the text of the child elements are blurred. Why?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect />
    </Grid.Effect>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Background="White">Test</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Update:

with shadow

[image]

without shadow

[image]

Comment: It does not happen to me, post more code or a screenshot

Comment: I'm working with Windows XP over Parallels on my Mac, could this be the problem?

Comment: Good question. I work with Visual Studio 2010 Express. Where can I find the version of the WPF?

Comment: @Smolla should be 4, anyway check the version on PresentationCore

Comment: @Smolla tryed with 2010 too, same as in kaxaml test is ok on my side

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The reason why the text is blurred is because Effects cause the elements and all sub-elements to be rendered into a Bitmap first. This means that sub-pixel rendering (ClearType) cannot take place and therefore the text appears lower-quality.

You can work around this by applying the effect to only parts of your visual tree. The parts that don't contain the text.

In your case you probably want something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Border>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Background="White">Test</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer since it's clearly the right one. I think you might need to set the backround on the border instead of the textblok below for the drop shadow to show, since it wont show if border has not visual part to cast the shadow from.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your answer, which I accepted. Sorry for the delay ;)

Comment: The accepted answer cannot be entirely correct, because in my case (where the shadow is directly on the text but the effect is applied to the ContentProvider) is fine in the designer but not in the running app. There's something more going on here.

Comment: You can also try `<DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality" />` This has helped me.

Comment: I tried this but depending on the location on the screen, the border is offset by a pixel in different directions, presumably due to rounding.

Answer (score 25):

It may be a problem with subpixels.

Try to add `UseLayoutRounding = "True"` to the grid.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` to the TextBlock as shown in [WPF Blurry fonts problem - Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions).
The effect might somehow increase the "bluriness" by e.g. moving the grid some fractions of a pixel or so.

Comment: This didn't change anything :(

Comment: Try adding it to the TextBlock, not the Grid.