# SnapsToDevicePixels seems to not work in StackPanel

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, stackpanel, blurry, snapstodevicepixels

I have more expanders in StackPanel (Orientation=Vertical). When I expand one, the others below the expanded one seem to be blured. Like it would SnapsToDevicePixels=False.

I think the problem could be in StackPanel because it doesn't support UseLayoutRounding in .NET 3.5 (which I use) yet. Is that possible or the problem could be elsewhere?

I put SnapsToDevicePixels="True" almost everywhere I could, but nothing changed.

(Font has size 12 so it couldn't be [1]: [WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions))

Comment: What type of Panel do you have inside the Expander?
I tried with Grid and it was blurry. If I use another StackPanel inside the expander it looks fine.

Comment: @SvenG It's Grid. I tried StackPanel without success. It doesn't appear everytime. Different expanders make others blurry or not. It probably depends on how exactly it's placed on the pixels grid.

Answer (score 5):

Try set UseLayoutRounding property it should adjust layout to use position rounded to integer.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpfs-most-important-property-uselayoutrounding

Comment: He said he used NET 3.5, why do you recommend something which is not available?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem with RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"