# How to draw a rotated string with high quality in C#?

Tags: c#, graphics, user-controls

I want to draw a string and rotate it with a custom angle. Simply, I calculate the new dimenstions of the area that contains the rotated image, then create a bitmap object and by means of graphics object of it, I draw a string with 3 transformations (translation to the center, rotation, and reverse translation). I wrote the following code but the quality is not desired. Does anyone have an idea?

```
    private Image RotateText(string Text, int FontSize, float Angle)
    {

        //Modify angle
        Angle *= -1;

        //Calculate rotation angle in radian
        double AngleInRadian = (Angle * 2 * Math.PI) / 360d;

        //Instantiate a font for text
        Font TextFont = new Font("Tahoma", FontSize, FontStyle.Bold);

        //Measure size of the text
        Graphics Graphic = this.CreateGraphics();
        SizeF TextSize = Graphic.MeasureString(Text, TextFont);

        //Calculate size of the rotated text
        double NewWidth  = Math.Abs(TextSize.Width * Math.Cos(AngleInRadian)) + Math.Abs(TextSize.Height * Math.Sin(AngleInRadian));
        double NewHeight = Math.Abs(TextSize.Width * Math.Sin(AngleInRadian)) + Math.Abs(TextSize.Height * Math.Cos(AngleInRadian));

        //Instantiate a new image for rotated text
        Bitmap RotatedText = new Bitmap((int)(Math.Round(NewWidth)), (int)(Math.Round(NewHeight)));

        //Get graphic object of new isntantiated image for painting
        Graphics TextGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(RotatedText);
        TextGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

        //Calcaute coordination of center of the image
        float OX = (float)NewWidth  / 2f;
        float OY = (float)NewHeight / 2f;

        //Apply transformations (translation, rotation, reverse translation)
        TextGraphic.TranslateTransform(OX, OY);
        TextGraphic.RotateTransform(Angle);
        TextGraphic.TranslateTransform(-OX, -OY);

        //Calculate the loaction of drawing text
        float X = (RotatedText.Width  - TextSize.Width ) / 2f;
        float Y = (RotatedText.Height - TextSize.Height) / 2f;

        //Draw the string
        TextGraphic.DrawString(Text, TextFont, Brushes.White, X, Y);

        //Return the image of rotated text
        return RotatedText;

    }
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: //Calculate size of the rotated text
        double NewWidth  = Math.Abs(TextSize.Width * Math.Cos(AngleInRadian)) + Math.Abs(TextSize.Height * Math.Sin(AngleInRadian));
        double NewHeight = Math.Abs(TextSize.Width * Math.Sin(AngleInRadian)) + Math.Abs(TextSize.Height * Math.Cos(AngleInRadian));    Is this calculation in your code correct ?

Comment: Should it be like                                         //Calculate size of the rotated text
double NewWidth  = Math.Abs(TextSize.Width * Math.Cos(AngleInRadian));
                                                                double NewHeight = Math.Abs(TextSize.Width * Math.Sin(AngleInRadian));

Comment: Now, I'm looking for calculating the exact width and height of rotated text. I checked the following link for calculation http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-side-right-triangle.html  Checking the above link shows formula in my 2nd comment. But most of the developers are using your code (in my first comment). So, I'm just curious to know which one is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `TextRenderingHint` property of your `Graphics` object to `AntiAlias`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint.aspx

Comment: This won't work when capturing to bitmap and rotating. There is no hinting when rendering a bitmap at an angle

Comment: Actually, that is not what is happening here. If you follow the code, you can tell that the `RotatedText` bitmap actually holds a prerotated text. The bitmap will not get rotated - the text is already rotated on the bitmap. So TextRendering will make a difference. Also, if the case were as you say, the results would not look like the resulting picture.

Comment: Thanks Anders, that works well, using TranslateTransform.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a few things:

- In your XAML:

  TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" (and other TextOptions attached properties)
- In your C#:

  TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
- Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions) SO topic

Comment: The question is about rendering using System.Drawing - not about WPF.

Comment: @atornblad as you said, the problem is about rendering, and he renders using WPF. He can use attached properties in C# code just the same. (I edit to show C# usage)

Comment: No, he uses `Graphics.DrawString` to render text.

Comment: You can't render using WPF in WinForms applications. This answer doesn't make any sense. The WPF blurry fonts syndrome is not an issue here.