# How to get rid of the blurry fonts for menus when using WPF?

Tags: wpf, clarity

WPF beginner here. I'm trying to mimic the font style used in Visual Studio 2010 for menus. Under Windows XP menus look blurry.

[image: screenshot]

How can my code be changed to get the same result?

```
<Window x:Class="Test_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
            <MenuItem Header="_View" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Window" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Blurry fonts problem - Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions)

Comment: @Joey: Indeed. The answer of Helge Klein is the one that I was looking for. Unfortunately it's not the top answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play around with the following parameters for your `Window`:

```
    <Window x:Class="Test_WPF.MainWindow"
           ....
    UseLayoutRounding="True"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType">
```

Comment: TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the blurring was caused by a `DropShadowEffect` applied on a wrapped `Grid`.
Removing this effect makes the blur issue disappear.