# WPF custom font not rendering properly

Tags: wpf, fonts, expression-blend

I am using the font "Code Bold" for a WPF application, font is embedded and looks to be working in Expression Blend and the WPF designer.

As shown here:
[image]

The bottom text looks to be better antialised. What could be a problem here (except that the font sizes don't match).

I already added these tags to the control and parent window:

```
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
```

Does it have to do that the font is not Cleartype?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try playing with `SnapsToDevicePixels` or `UseLayoutRounding` (depending on version of WPF) on yourelements that use the text, between all of these settings you should get what you need.

Comment: Thanks will do that. This textbox is in a border control, but I read somewhere that you can better but a rectangle behind it, I will check that too.

Answer (score 0):

`UseLayoutRounding="True"` worked for me.
I'm using: **WPF .NET 4.5**.

I also tried `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` and `RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"` but these made no difference.

In my case I am creating custom controls. I set UseLayoutRounding in the style sheet of the custom control. All control instances are now rendering text correctly.