# Pixellated and Broken Text on WPF Animation

Tags: wpf, animation, fonts, blurry

I have a control with an animation applied on the `Height` property. The control contains a `ListBox` with `TextBlock` as `ListItem`. But the text is blurred, broken, or pixellated during animation. Below please see the images during different points in the animation.

[image: Blurred "Ready For Operation]

[image: Broken text " Tripped Circuit Breaker ...]

[image: Relatively better text]

The code of my `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Description"
Padding="0,2,0,2"
Grid.Column="1" 
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
Text="{Binding Description}"
ToolTip="{Binding Description}"
TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
Foreground="White"
FontSize="11" FontFamily="{DynamicResource StandardFontType}"/>
```

I tried all different options for `TextOptions.TextRenderingMode` and `DisplayModes` from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions#190521), but nothing could solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching between:

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
```

and

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
```

Also please note that Borders with shadows can cause trouble with Text rendering, [see this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631635/677014)

As described in that link, you can have the best of both worlds (the shadows + the nicely rendered text) by using a Grid and putting both elements in the same Row/Column: they are therefore superimposed but the text won't suffer from the shadow.

Comment: I already tried both these options, but same problem stays. With TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display", a little better look, but still very ugly and broken.

Comment: Try dissociating the text from the shadowed element

Comment: That did the magic. I removed dropshadow for the control and it worked for me. But I lost the shadow effect :(.

Comment: super @Baboon... with a little modification, now I got ShadowEffect also working with fixed text. Thank you very much for support.