# WPF Datagrid - DataBinding C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm fresh new to WPF, and I've been trying to populate a DataGrid, but it shows no values...

As you can see: http://i.epvpimg.com/EJ0Bh.png

Code:

```
List<FileI> files = new List<FileI>();
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("profileSettings"))
{
    files.Add(new FilI( { fileName = file, fileSize = new FileInfo(file).Length }));
}

dgFilesToExtract.ItemsSource = files;
```

I checked the folder, there are 2 files, and I placed a BP before the ItemsSource property is set, and the list has items.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `File` class define properties over the variables and set `AutogenerateColumns = true` on your datagrid

Comment: Glad it worked for you...also pls read the editing help H.B. provided...it will help you take the max benefit from stackoverflow community

Comment: So I should create a new question, regarding this blurry font problem?

Comment: yes, you should always post a separate question and not combine them into one.

Answer (score 2):

Your file class only contains *fields* but you can only bind to *properties*. Read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the `ItemsSource` property of the grid in code **AND** binding it in the XAML.  Try removing the binding statement in the XAML.

Comment: The XAML value is irrelevant to the problem as it gets replaced on click. Would remove it nonetheless because it of course serves no purpose.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't notice that it was being set inside code on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

About the Blurry Font problem. There are lots of topics on this take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions)