# WPF Rotated TextBlock look unclear

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have a Expander with a TextBlock assigned to the Header. It's rotated 90 degrees. The problem is that the Text look unclear:

[image: Unclear font]

As you can see the "Debug" isn't that sharp!
Is there a way to fix it?

MY XAML code is

```
<Window x:Class="Minecraft_Autocarafter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="220*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="277*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Name="RunButton"  Content="Run Bot" Click="RunButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="StopButton"  Content="Stop Bot" Click="StopButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,28,0,0" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="AblaufBox" Margin="100,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Started"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Checking Items"/>
        <!--<ListBoxItem Name="Start" Content="Started"/>
        <ListBoxItem Name="Start" Content="Started"/>-->
    </ListBox>



    <Expander Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,17,0" ExpandDirection="Right">
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Debug">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="25"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible">
            <ListBox Name="DebugListBox">
                <ListBoxItem Content="Test"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Oh, and I started WPF one hour before, so don't flame me please :D

Comment: You are using RenderTransform, this transform the texTblock rendering the text and can get pixeled. You must render the Layout with "TextBlock.LayoutTransform" and this will transform the entire Layout from the TextBlock. This will work better. Greetings!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 <Expander Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,17,0" ExpandDirection="Right">
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Debug" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
            </TextBlock>
        </Expander.Header>
 </Expander>
```

please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode` but `TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated"` should probably be mentioned as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting properties for `TextBlock`:

```
UseLayoutRounding="True" OR SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
```