# Getting blur text only if the window is not maximized in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, cleartype

I know that there are a lot of questions about this subject but it seems that no one tells why this is happening:

Maximized window: [image: no blur]

unmaxmimized window: [image]

This only seems happen when I have the medium or the larger setting, with the smaller the text is always sharp:
[image]

this is happening for all the text in the application, I already checked that the clear type is enabled and I read something about the allow transparency property I tried with both true and false but nothing changes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you seen the stuff about pixel snapping? I'm not sure if it applies here or or not, though... Sounds a lot like how Adobe made a bunch of money with fonts. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: just tried SnapsToDevicePixels="True", no changes.

Comment: Might be good information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the text options?

```
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the XAML:

`<Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display"/>`

Also, not set the value to "Ideal" which is there by default.

`<Viewbox Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Georgia">My Cool Text</TextBlock>
</Viewbox>`

Could be a bug in WPF but this workaround is in place for many users!