# WPF blurry font in one control

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, wpf-4.0

I have the problem, that the font in my application is blurry. The curious thing is, that only one control (Grid with Columns and Rows) is blurry, the rest works perfect:

[image: Blurry Grid-Control]

I have tried the following parameter, but that changed nothing:

```
RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" 
TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" 
TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType"
SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

The same control (First is correct, second is blurry):

[image: Same Control]

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this problem, thank you!

**ANSWER**:
The problem was solved by using (Thank you Heena Patil):

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-problem-solutions

Comment: Try SnapToDevicePixels = true

Comment: @Heea Patil: I have read this article before, it did not help. I've tried all mentioned methods, but still the same result.

Comment: @kidshaw: SnapToDevicePixels  also doesn't work

Comment: Long shot, but do you have any effects associated with the control stack?

Comment: Can't be, because i use the same control multiple times in the same window. The second one is only in a resizable grid. (See new picture)

Comment: The grid renders itself without ClearType.  Unlike the rest of the text in your screenshot.  Ought to have something to do with that specific grid control.

Comment: RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" or RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"

Comment: @Heena Patil: Perfect, this was the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using

[RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode.aspx) and [RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.edgemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

> RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" or RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"