# Blurry textblock text with the same code

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 different applications. Both applications check the connection to a WCF-Service. The result is bound to the view.

The XAML code of for both `TextBlock`s in the first and second application are exactly the same. Nevertheless, one of the textblocks got a strange blur effect. The right one on the picture:

[image: Text blur]

XAML code for both textblocks:

```
   <!--Connection Status-->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Server: " Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Calibri" >
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="330" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="4" Color="Black"/>
            </TextBlock.Effect>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding connectionStatus}" Foreground="{Binding connectionColor}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Calibri" >
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="330" Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="4" />
            </TextBlock.Effect>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

What could cause this strange behavior?

**Edit:**
The possible duplicate [WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions) does not address my problem. I could not find a solution or an explanation for this strange behavior.
I don't have a general problem with WPF Text rendering.

Comment: Do you have any styling/theming in your projects?

Comment: Yes but it only sets a standard Foreground,FontSize and FontFamily. Thats all

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1631635/1095741 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions)