# WPF Viewbox Textrendering blurry on runtime (not designtime)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, text-rendering

At designtime (in VS2015) everything looks okay (upper).

But, at runtime (bottom), the text-rendering goes totally wrong.

[image: Difference in rendering]

My markup (simplified):

```
<Window>
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="10:00" FontSize="16" 
                FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Verdana" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Edit time" FontSize="16" 
                FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

I've already tried to add `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"` to `Window`, `ViewBox`, `Grid` and `Label`. But the rendering still looks blurry.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions ?

Comment: Why do you use ViewBox with Grid?

Comment: @A191919: The inner `Grid` is used to layout the parts of the `View` to be hosted inside the `Viewbox`. The question contains just the simplified version of the real code.