# how to keep the quality of a text on small font sizes in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a UWP project. I added some fonts to the project but, they lose their quality in small sizes and does not render very well

In wpf, `textoption` is used to solve this problem. But this Is not supported in uwp.
What should I do?
Similar problems in wpf:
[WPF Blurry fonts issue- Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Any additional info would be helpful:
1) what fonts are you experiencing this with?
2) what is the resolution of the devices you're using?
3) steps to replicate? what controls are you using and what font-size?

I work with nearly the entire google fonts catalogue in my UWP app and I haven't experienced this except with particular fonts that admittedly do not display well at smaller sizes (regardless of application/device).

It seems like the WPF issue was fixed with .Net 4.0 - hard to imagine there would be the same issue with UWP that's still not fixed by 4.6...