# How to imitate OuterGlowBitmapEffect using WPF effects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, effects, glow

I tried using DropShadowEffect but it's "glow" strength weakens when you increase BlurRadius. I want to have strong outer glow like the image below.

[image]

If I stack the same effect a dozen times I am able to get this, but the performance tanks after this. Is this possible to do using WPF with a single effect?

Comment: If you have very specific requirement like this then there are two alternatives I would suggest. 1) Write your own effect. It'll do whatever you want then. 2) Use a imagebrush - if you can build it once, capture and re-use as a picture then it doesn't matter how expensive that building process was.

Comment: One way to build such an image programmatically would be to use writeablebitmap.  This is pretty fast. I build one 1155 x 805 for map backgrounds in our game and it takes 20 odd milliseconds. You'd want a faster simper algorithm than gaussian to work out the strength of colour for each px. That needn't be too precise if you then blur the image.

Comment: One simple solution is to surround the targeted control with an Image control that points to a shadow .PNG file with transparency (something like this https://i.imgur.com/T7uNORE.png) that you can stretch to the control size. The benefit is you can finely craft the image you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how large you want the radius of the blur to be and how smooth the result needs to be, you could stack different effects like gradient stops instead of repeatedly stacking the same effect.

---

Like you pointed out, the [`DropShadowEffect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect?view=net-5.0) strength gets weaker as the `BlurRadius` increases.

[image: Example of a WPF control]

```xml
<TextBox Text="DropShadowEffect">
    <TextBox.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="50"
                          ShadowDepth="0" 
                          Color="Blue" 
                          Opacity="1"/>
    </TextBox.Effect>
</TextBox>
```

---

Additionally, applying effects directly to the `TextBox` [impacts the rendering quality of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190344/wpf-blurry-fonts-issue-solutions). The proposed solution to the linked question (setting `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` on the `Window`) also has layout implications. Instead, you can draw a [`Rectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.rectangle?view=net-5.0) with a [`BlurEffect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect?view=net-5.0) behind your element.

[image: Example of a WPF control]

```xml
<Rectangle Fill="Blue"
           Height={Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualHeight}"
           Width={Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <Rectangle.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="50"/>
    </Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Rectangle with BlurEffect"/>
```

---

You can then add an additional `Rectangle` for each gradient stop. Here there are two: one at `50` to define the overall size of the blur, and one at `30` to strengthen the glow around the control.

[image: Example of a WPF control]

```xml
<Rectangle Fill="Blue"
           Height={Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualHeight}"
           Width={Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <Rectangle.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="50"/>
    </Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
<Rectangle Fill="Blue"
           Height={Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualHeight}"
           Width={Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <Rectangle.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="30"/>
    </Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Two Rectangles with BlurEffect"/>
```

---

You asked about the perceived sharpness around the corners of the `TextBox` and I must admit I don't have a good solution. I initially considered rounding the corners of the blurred elements behind your control by using a [`Border`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.border?view=net-5.0) instead of a `Rectangle`, but I honestly don't see much of a difference.

[image: Example of a WPF control]

```xml
<!-- Remove the CornerRadius property for square corners. -->
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Blue">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="50"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Blue">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="30"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

---

Of course, you could always make the background objects larger than your control. Here they are in the same cell of a `Grid` but there is extra space for the `Border` to grow because the `TextBox` has a [`Margin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin?view=net-5.0). A smaller top/bottom margin and larger left/right margin means the glow will be more uniform around the control.

[image: Example of a WPF control]

```xml
<!-- These items should be in the same cell of a Grid -->
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Blue">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="50"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Blue">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect Radius="30"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
<TextBox Text="TextBox has an 8px, 4px margin" Margin="8 4"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One thing with rectangle is you can notice the corners look sharp, not as round as the glow effect in OP. Is there a way to fix that? Basically to have a rounder glow that's uniform around the control.

Comment: I don't think there's a good solution since the `BlurEffect` will approximate an ellipse unless your control is close to square. I added a section about using a different size for the background object that might suit your needs.